# How to have change detection with material-dropdown-select if using a SelectionOptions

Tags: angular, dart, material-design, angular-material2

I have the following implementation of a material-dropdown-select and it works beautifully.

```
<material-dropdown-select [buttonText]="organizer?.name">
  <material-select-item *ngFor="let sailingClub of sailingClubs"
    {{sailingClub.name}}
  </material-select-item>
</material-dropdown-select>
```

My data is coming from this property:

```
Iterable<SailingClub> get sailingClubs => _store.state.sailingClubs.values;
```

The nice thing about it is that the items automatically update once the backend (firebase) adds new items to the list.

Now I want to change it to use the searchable dropdown.
For this I have to convert the data into SelectionOptions and with that I have problems. Everything works fine but I no longer get the change detection.
It is not really surprising since I now have to create a static SelectionOptions instance and that is the only thing I am handing to the view component.

```
<material-dropdown-select [buttonText]="organizer?.name"
  [options]="filteredSailingClubs"
  [itemRenderer]="displayNameRenderer">
  <div header>
    <material-select-searchbox
      label="Search..."
      [filterable]="filteredSailingClubs">
    </material-select-searchbox>
  </div>
</material-dropdown-select>
```

and this is how I create the filteredSailingClubs

```
filteredSailingClubs = new StringSelectionOptions(_store.state.sailingClubs.values, toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer);
```

and access the name property

```
ItemRenderer<SailingClub> displayNameRenderer = (SailingClub item) => item.name;
```

Comment: I haven't used Firebase myself yet and don't know what kind of value(s) it returns. I think you need to listen to updates and then do something like `filteredSailingClubs.optionGroups = [new OptionGroup(_store.state.sailingClubs.values)])`

Comment: Two quick questions:

Does your store object have a way to listen to changes to it?  Something like

class Store {

Stream<Null> get onStoreChanged => ...

}

And is the `sailingClubs` property of the state a Map, List, or something else?

Comment: What change detection strategy are you using? Does it work if you change it?

Comment: Thanks for the interest in my question. About the store object. It is like a redux store (using the greencat library). The store.state variable itself is a regular class with several maps inside of it. On a change the class is copied with the changed maps as input. So the old state is never changed but a new one is created. Therefore I also don't have any streams or even a change strategy. On a change just the store.state variable is updated and regular material_components just pick up this change an redraw themself. Only the dropdown with search does not work since it can't pickup the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my final solution. It is not really great in my opinion since it still requires quite some code but at least it works very well.
The main reason for the amount of code is that the map.values list itself is not stable. So each new comparison of map.values with the old values would return true. Even if the map is unchanged. Therefore we have to save the original map.

```
StringSelectionOptions<SailingClub> _filteredSailingClubs;
Map<String, SailingClub> _oldSailingClubs;
SelectionModel<SailingClub> _singleSelectModel;
SailingClub _oldOrganizer;
StreamSubscription _selectionListener;

StringSelectionOptions<SailingClub> get filteredSailingClubs {
  // We have to save the old state since the Iterable itself is unstable and would change all the time
  if (_oldSailingClubs != _store.state.sailingClubs) {
    _oldSailingClubs = _store.state.sailingClubs;
    _filteredSailingClubs =
      new StringSelectionOptions(_store.state.sailingClubs.values, toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer);
  }
  return _filteredSailingClubs;
}

SelectionModel<SailingClub> get singleSelectModel {
  // We have to update the selection model on organizer change
  if (_singleSelectModel == null || _oldOrganizer != organizer) {
    _oldOrganizer = organizer;
    _singleSelectModel = new SelectionModel<SailingClub>.withList(selectedValues: [organizer]);
    _selectionListener?.cancel();
    _selectionListener = _singleSelectModel.selectionChanges.listen(update);
  }
  return _singleSelectModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you listening to your Firebase database for changes?

I'm not sure exactly what `_store` or any of its properties are, but from a Firebase [DatabaseRef](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/firebase/4.1.0/firebase/DatabaseReference-class.html), you can listen for changes, and update your selection options. Change detection should then detect that the selection options have changed.

```dart
sailingClubsRef.onValue((value) {
  filteredSailingClubs = new StringSelectionOptions(
    value.snapshot.val(),
    toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer,
  );  
});
```

Comment: I now added an answer to show my current approach. My store itself is a redux store which has no knowledge of the gui. And the firebase callback also does not know anything about the gui and e.g. StringSelection. It just creates a new event sending a change to the store. It works great for all gui components including the dropdown-select except if I have to use the search api.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my current, approach. Posting it as an answer for better readability.

First I had to add new variables for the calculated values and to manually keep track of changes.

```
StringSelectionOptions<SailingClub> filteredSailingClubs;
SelectionModel<SailingClub> singleSelectModel;
Map<String, SailingClub> oldSailingClubs;
SailingClub oldOrganizer;
```

Then in the constructor of my component I can create the filteredSailingClubs. But this StringSelection will be empty since at that time all the options are not loaded from firebase.

```
filteredSailingClubs = new StringSelectionOptions(_store.state.sailingClubs.values, toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer);
```

and to finally be able to update the filteredSailingClubs I had to add this.

```
void ngDoCheck() {
  if (oldSailingClubs != _store.state.sailingClubs) {
    oldSailingClubs = _store.state.sailingClubs;
    filteredSailingClubs =
        new StringSelectionOptions(_store.state.sailingClubs.values, toFilterableString: displayNameRenderer);
  }
  if (oldOrganizer != organizer) {
    oldOrganizer = organizer;
    singleSelectModel = new SelectionModel<SailingClub>.withList(selectedValues: [organizer]);
    singleSelectModel.selectionChanges.listen(update);
  }
}
```

and here is one more callback that allows me to update a value when the selection changed in the gui

```
void update(List<SelectionChangeRecord> record) {
  if (record.isNotEmpty && record.first.added.isNotEmpty) {
    onOrganizerChanged(record.first.added.first);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is a lot of boiler plate code just to make the list searchable. Before all the change detection was handled by Angular and completely hidden. Therefore I wonder if I do it wrong.

I also don't want to change the structure of my store. It is basically a redux pattern store (using greencat) and is immutable.
I also don't want my store to know anything about the gui or e.g. a selectionmodel etc.

My next step would be to derive from the material-dropdown-select itself and see if I can hide the complexity there.

Comment: Why do you need a try statement and why don't you log whatever it catches? Did you omit it here for brevity? You should cancel previous subscriptions to selectionChanges before creating a new model and a new subscription, it might be one of the problems breaking your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with canceling previous subscriptions, I will implement that. The reason for the try catch is that the organizer can be null so I need better checks for this condition, I just added the try catch for a quick proof of concept. But this is not the problem with my code. The issue is, how to make the material-dropdown aware of changes. My solution works but is so much boiler plate code :-(